# Package libcxxabi installed but not found in conda

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I tried to create a new environment through a yml file in terminal but encountered this error

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:

- libcxxabi=8.0
```

When I ran `conda list` , I actually found these pkg installed

```
libcxx                    8.0.1                         0    conda-forge
libcxxabi                 8.0.1                         0    conda-forge/label/b
```

I don't know why this error still comes out

Comment: What OS are you on? https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libcxxabi

Comment: Catalina 10.15.3

Comment: From the page I shared above, it seems that the latest version of libcxxabi available for macOS is 4.0.1. I'm confused now....

Comment: yeah I also noticed that. I actually installed the one with label as broken maybe that's the problem?

Comment: That would make sense, yeah.